# How to discard unused function after optimization in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I got problems with GCC optimization,

when I use `gcc test.c -Os` or `gcc test.c -O2`,
the main() function will put at start address.

but some unused function like `<_start>` `<exit>` `<memset>`, why are they still there?

I have try to use `-ffunction-sections` `-fdata-sections` or `-gc-sections`, it doesn't work.

my simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char buff[20];
sprintf(buff, "%s%d", "hello", 6);
return 0; }
```

Comment: Why do you think `sprintf` can work without `memset` or even `exit` for that matter?

Comment: You can try manually discarding these functions and check it the binaries link properly. If they don't, you can know where these functions are being referenced.

Comment: But I use optimization and the compiler never used or invoked.

Comment: i don't understand why unused but still generated

Comment: I can guarantee you that `_start` and `exit` are definitely used. And it's very likely that `memset` is used by either `_start` or `sprintf`. `main` isn't the entry point to your program, `_start` is usually the entry point.

Comment: If you don't want to "see" these functions then you need to construct the program in another way. Read about gcc freestanding. In hosted environment these functions are necessary to set up and clean up different things before and after main.

Comment: If performance is important, you _do not use stdio.h_.

Comment: I want this function but I can't include header file? how to implement? haha... thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

`_start` is generally the real entrypoint of your executable (the one that initializes the C runtime before calling `main`); `exit` is implicitly invoked when `main` terminates. `memset` is implicitly invoked by the compiler in a variety of situations (for example when zero-initializing buffers on the stack), or may be used by the `printf` implementation.

Comment: Yes, but now, there have a option `-Os`.I try to follow the program process, and I never found any function invoke it.

Comment: _start is called after OS loads the program, _start calls main, when main returns, exit is called. You won't be able to observe this if you are not disassembling the executable (not the object code), these injections are made at link time.

Comment: I use `objdump -d` to generate disassemble file. after the optimization `-Os`, the main() in start address 0x0 or 0x10000, and secondary is _start but never used, does it has some implicitly invoked in other way? I didn't find it.

Comment: @WuCheng: on Linux the real entry point of the executable is `_start`, which is "called" by the kernel and *then* calls your `main`. Of course it isn't used by another function - it is the executable entrypoint.